# Pandas Date MultiIndex with missing dates - Rolling sum

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a pandas series that looks like

```
Attribute      DateEvent     Value
Type A         2015-04-01    4
               2015-04-02    5
               2015-04-05    3
Type B         2015-04-01    1
               2015-04-03    4
               2015-04-05    1
```

How do I convert the values to a rolling sum (say, past two days) while making sure to account for missing dates in my DateEvent index (assuming the start date and end date of it are the full range? (For example, `2015-04-03` and `2015-04-04` are missing for Type A, and `2015-04-02` and `2015-04-04` are missing for Type B).

Answer (score 8):

I've made a couple assumptions about what you want, **please clarify**:

1. You want the rows that have missing dates, to be considered as having `Value = NaN`.
2. As a result, the **past 2 day** rolling sum should return `NaN` anytime there's a missing date in the rolling window.
3. You want to compute the rolling sum **within in each group** `Type A` and `Type B`

If I've assumed correctly,

### Create sample data set

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

datastring = io.StringIO(
"""
Attribute,DateEvent,Value
Type A,2017-04-02,1
Type A,2017-04-03,2
Type A,2017-04-04,3
Type A,2017-04-05,4
Type B,2017-04-02,1
Type B,2017-04-03,2
Type B,2017-04-04,3
Type B,2017-04-05,4
""")

s = pd.read_csv(
            datastring, 
            index_col=['Attribute', 'DateEvent'],
            parse_dates=True)
print(s)
```

Here's what it looks like. Each of `Type A` and `Type B` are missing `2017-04-01`.

```
                      Value
Attribute DateEvent        
Type A    2017-04-02      1
          2017-04-03      2
          2017-04-04      3
          2017-04-05      4
Type B    2017-04-02      1
          2017-04-03      2
          2017-04-04      3
          2017-04-05      4
```

### Solution

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390336/how-to-fill-the-missing-record-of-pandas-dataframe-in-pythonic-way), you have to reconstruct the index, then re-index your `Series` to get one that includes all the dates.

```
# reconstruct index with all the dates
dates = pd.date_range("2017-04-01","2017-04-05", freq="1D")
attributes = ["Type A", "Type B"]
# create a new MultiIndex
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([attributes,dates], 
        names=["Attribute","DateEvent"])
# reindex the series
sNew = s.reindex(index)
```

The missing dates were added, with `Value = NaN`.

```
                      Value
Attribute DateEvent        
Type A    2017-04-01    NaN
          2017-04-02    1.0
          2017-04-03    2.0
          2017-04-04    3.0
          2017-04-05    4.0
Type B    2017-04-01    NaN
          2017-04-02    1.0
          2017-04-03    2.0
          2017-04-04    3.0
          2017-04-05    4.0
```

Now group the `Series` by the `Attribute` index column and apply a rolling window of size `2` with `sum()`

```
# group the series by the `Attribute` column
grouped = sNew.groupby(level="Attribute")
# Apply a 2 day rolling window
summed = grouped.rolling(2).sum()
```

### Final Output

```
                                Value
Attribute Attribute DateEvent        
Type A    Type A    2017-04-01    NaN
                    2017-04-02    NaN
                    2017-04-03    3.0
                    2017-04-04    5.0
                    2017-04-05    7.0
Type B    Type B    2017-04-01    NaN
                    2017-04-02    NaN
                    2017-04-03    3.0
                    2017-04-04    5.0
                    2017-04-05    7.0
```

*Final Note: No idea why there are now two `Attribute` index columns, let me know if anyone figures that out.*

EDIT: Turns out similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42129254/pandas-dataframe-multiindex-groupby-rolling-operation-with-missing-dates). Check it out.

*Source:* [How to fill in missing values with a multiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390336/how-to-fill-the-missing-record-of-pandas-dataframe-in-pythonic-way)