# Is there a way to do rolling count with groupby 2 columns in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to be able to count the occurrences of a location over a 7 day period. I have tried several ways of combining groupby, rolling and Grouper but still not getting the result I want. How can I groupby 2 columns to get the result I want?

Here is an example table:

```
locations = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','C']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': times,'location': locations})
```

```
     date     location
0   2014-08-25  A
1   2014-08-26  B
2   2014-08-26  A
3   2014-09-11  B
4   2014-09-12  C
5   2014-09-15  C
```

I've tried:

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df['roll']=df.groupby('location')['location'].rolling(7).count().reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

but get me this:

```
         location   roll
date        
2014-08-25  A   1.0
2014-08-26  B   2.0
2014-08-26  A   1.0
2014-09-11  B   2.0
2014-09-12  C   1.0
2014-09-15  C   2.0
```

My desired output should look something like this:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2014-08-25','2014-08-26','2014-08-26','2014-09-11','2014-09-12', '2014-09-15']))
locations = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','C']
count = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': times,'location': locations, 'rolling_count':count})

    date    location    rolling_count
0   2014-08-25  A   1
1   2014-08-26  B   1
2   2014-08-26  A   2
3   2014-09-11  B   1
4   2014-09-12  C   1
5   2014-09-15  C   2
```

Comment: Does this post help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261823/pandas-date-multiindex-with-missing-dates-rolling-sum

Answer (score 1):

To count the occurrences of a location over a 7 day period might be done by a `Grouper` such as `df.groupby(Grouper(key='date', freq='7d'))`.

But doing counts of observations in a rolling window provides more information.  This is not 'weekly' which in itself is always hard to define and should always be avoided when crunching calendar years and months.

For a rolling count of unique observations that are all in one column.  So some tricks are necessary:

- Pivot the DataFrame and get the locations into columns.  This greatly
  facilitates counting unique observations.
- Normalize the datetime index. This enables a 7 day window to be slid
  along the index.

The result is that as the window slides over the observations, the counts increase and then decrease.

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)

times = ['2014-08-25', '2014-08-26', '2014-08-26', '2014-09-11', '2014-09-12', '2014-09-15', '2014-09-16']
locations = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C','C', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': times,'location': locations})

# multiple locations can be observed in a single day
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='location', values='location')

# set up a datetime index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# normalize the days so an entire 7 day window can be rolled
df = df.resample('1d').last()

# count the number of observations in the window per location
# TODO: functional way to do this?
for col in df.columns:
    df['{}_7d_observations'.format(col)] = df[col].rolling(7).count()

print(df)
```

Produces something like

```
location      A    B    C  A_7d_observations  B_7d_observations  C_7d_observations
date                                                                              
2014-08-25    A  NaN  NaN                1.0                0.0                0.0
2014-08-26    A    B  NaN                2.0                1.0                0.0
...snip...
2014-08-31  NaN  NaN  NaN                2.0                1.0                0.0
2014-09-01  NaN  NaN  NaN                1.0                1.0                0.0
...snip...
2014-09-10  NaN  NaN  NaN                0.0                0.0                0.0
2014-09-11  NaN    B  NaN                0.0                1.0                0.0
2014-09-12  NaN  NaN    C                0.0                1.0                1.0
2014-09-13  NaN  NaN  NaN                0.0                1.0                1.0
2014-09-14  NaN  NaN  NaN                0.0                1.0                1.0
2014-09-15  NaN  NaN    C                0.0                1.0                2.0
2014-09-16  NaN  NaN    C                0.0                1.0                3.0
```