# Python pandas - Efficiently apply function over rolling window by group with missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

**Note:** I already know the answer to this question, i am posting it just because i couldn't find proper answer on stack overflow and it took me surprising amount of time to figure it out. That being said, feel free to suggest other options.

**The Question**

I have a pandas DataFrame with three columns, one keeps a track of date, one keeps track of related observations (i.e. my grouping column) and third variable stores some numeric values. For each group in my dataframe, i'd like to calculate a rolling sum over the date column. **The caveat:** some dates are missing in the dataframe, i'd like to treat those as observations with value 0. I do not want to use cross join to add all the dates.

**Reproducible example**

Let's have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_col' : np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3]),
                  'value_col' : np.random.randint(0,5,size=14),
                  'dates' : pd.to_datetime(np.array([
                  '2018-01-01',
                  '2018-02-01',
                  '2018-03-01',
                  '2018-05-01',
                  '2018-06-01',
                  '2018-09-01',
                  '2018-01-01',
                  '2018-02-01',
                  '2018-05-01',
                  '2018-06-01',
                  '2018-07-01',
                  '2018-01-01',
                  '2018-02-01',
                  '2018-03-01'])
                  )}
                 )
```

The data looks something like this:

```
    id_col  value_col   dates
0   1   0   2018-01-01
1   1   1   2018-02-01
2   1   4   2018-03-01
3   1   0   2018-05-01
4   1   3   2018-06-01
5   1   3   2018-09-01
6   2   4   2018-01-01
7   2   3   2018-02-01
8   2   2   2018-05-01
9   2   0   2018-06-01
10  2   2   2018-07-01
11  3   4   2018-01-01
12  3   2   2018-02-01
13  3   3   2018-03-01
```

Approaches that i tried and do not work:

**Option 1:** completely ignores missing dates

```
df.groupby(['id_col']).rolling(2)['value_col'].sum().reset_index()
```

**Option 2:** Based on pandas [rolling documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), replace width of window using the pandas offset parameters (returns `ValueError: window must be an integer`). This approach would work if the dates column was used as index of a dataframe. Unfortunately, we can't use simple index here as 2 different IDs from id_col can contain the same date. (We could create MultiIndex, but then get the same value error).

```
df.groupby(['id_col']).rolling('60d')['value_col'].sum().reset_index()
```

What does work but isn't very straightforward:

**Option 1:** Cross join to fill in all missing dates (might be tough if you have a lot of data)

**Option 2:** Build multiindex from cartesian product of iterables as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261823/pandas-date-multiindex-with-missing-dates-rolling-sum?noredirect=1&lq=1). This is actually quite similar to the above option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `on` parameter of `rolling`. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) actually mentions it, although there is no example to see the appropriate usage.  Luckily, there is pandas github and [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/28297) issue, which, if you go through the comments, gives some insight on how to actually use the rolling function with offset windows properly.

Therefore, the solution would be:

```
df.groupby(['id_col']).rolling('60d', on = 'dates')['value_col'].sum().reset_index()
```

Note the ussage of `60d` as a proxy for 2 months instead of `2m` this is because `2m` would give you the following error: `ValueError: <2 * MonthEnds> is a non-fixed frequency`. For more on this issue, check the stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556344/pandas-monthly-rolling-operation).